React Native: How to Get Location Permission from single Popup like this
React native default permission PermissionsAndroid gets blocked after 3 tries, but this popup used in apps like TripAdvisor and Waze gets called every time without getting blocked the third time, how can I implement this in react native in a way that can ask the user each time to give access to location to the app without getting blocked and needing to go to the settings.

any help would be appreciated, thank you.
